# With ASP.NET MVC actions, should I use web services?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, jquery

In ASP.NET Web Forms if you want to use jQuery and call a method directly, you should either implement a web service, or use Page Methods. Also you can use Generic Handlers (.ashx files).

However, in ASP.NET MVC, a controller action (a method in nature) can be called directly from jQuery.

What web services has to offer in ASP.NET MVC world? In other words, seems that I can fulfill of my requirements via MVC's clean URLs, controllers and actions. Should I bother using Web Services?

Answer (score 1):

I think you got it all wrong regarding Web Services... Your page methods analogy is correct, but web services is a whole other ball game.

Here is a small, yet to the point, explanation on why use web services:

http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_why.asp

Wikipedia's definition for [Web Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) also gives you an insight into why they are used.

There are many reasons, but the main one, I would say, is [interoperability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interoperability).

But, yeah, if all you used web services for was to use jQuery to call a method directly, then you probably shouldn't use web services...